# Importing a self-signed SSL certificate on MacOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ssl, https

I generated a self-signed certificate with openssl and added it to my linux server.  I then imported the certificate on my mac with Keychain Access into the System keychain using the settings "Always Trust".

But, when I view the page in Chrome I'm still receiving an error:

```
The identity of this website has not been verified.
 • Server's certificate is not trusted.
```

[image: SSL Error in Chrome]

How do I get Chrome to trust my self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.robpeck.com/2010/10/google-chrome-mac-os-x-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/) you apparently have to open the certificate and set “When using this certificate” to “Always Trust” and also restart Chrome, in addition to what you mentioned having done.

By the way, https://shiing.com/ works as expected with Opera/Gentoo from here.

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick!  It's funny, I followed that guide but for some reason I skipped that last step having already clicked an "Always Trust" button.